# Operation && not working properly in PHP conditional statement

Tags: php

Why **if condition** is not meeting  and its printing **else statement** in below php code? It seems easy but certainly I am doing something wrong. Please explain. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$pk = 6;
$jk = 3;
$lk = 5;
$sk = 2;

if((!$pk==5) && ($jk == 3) && ($lk == 5) && ($sk == 2)){
echo 'All variable is true';
}

else{   
    echo 'one of them is wrong';
}
?>
```

Comment: It should be `($pk !== 5)` not `(!$pk==5)`.

Comment: `!$pk == 5` assesses `!$pk` first, and then the comparison

Comment: Short but very clear. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if((!$pk==5) && ($jk == 3) && ($lk == 5) && ($sk == 2)){
```

Should read:

```
if(($pk!==5) && ($jk == 3) && ($lk == 5) && ($sk == 2)){
```

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> $a != $b Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
>
> $a !== $b    Not identical   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: @PramodJha - no problem.  Please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if(($pk==5)&& ($jk == 3) && ($lk == 5) && ($sk == 2)){
echo 'All variable is true';
}
```